# How Laravel internally calls method, which have parameter, declared as instance of Request class?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There is some controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers; 
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function store (Request $request1) {

        $request2 = new Request();

    }
    ....
```

Here `$request1` and `$request2` objects are not same.

Question: why they aren't same? and how Laravel internally passes instance of  `Request` class to store() method? I thought it is something like: `UsersController::store( new Request )`. This is not correct?

Comment: I think because your `$request2` is you create new and is not related anything with `$request1` because `$request1` catch param when you post something into your `store function`. Anyway, I don't know why you create a new request for what?

Comment: Of course they're not the same. The `store` method receives already created `$request1` and inside the method you create a completely new object, with no data inside it. Why do you think they should be the same?

Comment: @vietnguyen09 - I don't want second(inside) request, I just want to understand how instance of Request class is passed to method internally

Comment: You're not answering my question, but regardless - [here's the code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7212b1e9620c36bf806e444f6931cf5f379c68ff/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php#L47). Laravel simply calls the controller action and passes the current request as the first argument. You're creating a completely new instance of `Request` with **no data**. The link I posted shows you how it does it internally.

Answer (score 1):

Your $request2 is New so its still empty..

while your $request1 has received data from POST.. So you can call your input value using the input name like so:

```
$request1->txt_someinputname1;
$request1->txt_someinputname2;
```